# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(nx)=\frac{1}{2}\cot(\frac{x}{2})$ in the sense of distributions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, distribution-theory

> Show that in the sense of distributions
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sin(nx)=\frac{1}{2}\cot(\frac{x}{2})$$

---

I know how to derive the result if this summation is finite, but how could I get this infinite sum from the finite case?

Comment: Are you sure about this result? I don't think the series should converge for most values of $x$.

Comment: HINT:Lagrange’s trigonometric
identities

Comment: link include Pdf file :https://ufile.io/8qh1i : there is "what" you want

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\sin } (n\theta ) = \frac{1}{2}\cot \frac{\theta }{2} - \frac{{\cos \left( {(N + \frac{1}{2})\theta } \right)}}{{2\sin \left( {\frac{\theta }{2}} \right)}}$$ to find close form:multiply with $$\frac{2sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{2sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$

Comment: The Cesaro sum exists, I think, but not the actual sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sense of [Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), the statement

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)\sim \frac12\cot(x/2)$$

is interpreted to mean that for any suitable test function $\phi(x)$ we have

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac12\cot(x/2)\right)\,dx \tag1$$

Evidently, the space of suitable test functions is restricted such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac12\cot(x/2)\right)\,dx<\infty\tag2$$

---

To see that $(1)$ is correct subject to $(2)$, we first note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx)= \frac12\cot(x/2)-\frac12 \csc(x/2)\cos((N+1/2)x)$$

Then upon applying the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) we find immediately that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\sin(nx)\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac12\cot(x/2)\right)\,dx\\\\
&-\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac12\csc(x/2)\cos((N+1/2)x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\left(\frac12\cot(x/2)\right)\,dx
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Im not familiar with distribution theory, so the first question is that the space of test function can be restricted ? and the second question is why Cantor-Lebesgue lemma can be applied to eliminate the second integral?? Thanks for your help very much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  First, yes the space of test functions is restricted here.  Second, I don't see how the Cantour-Lebesgue theorem applies.

Comment: Sorry, i mean Riemann Lebesgue lemma

Comment: It can be applied since $\phi(x)\csc(x/2)\in L^1$.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I'm quite busy in my report recently so i forget to reply this message.